# How To Calculate Height of Point B?

Tags: geometry

I have a survey point data which has coordinates X,Y, Height, Angle(Dip),Azimuth, and Depth(Distance). for Example, point A:

Easting: 290694

Northing: 715927

Elevation: 1060

Angle: 65°

Azimuth:45°

Distance:150

Can you please let me know hoe I can calculate the end point(End of trace) Height? Thanks for your time and comments

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fluent in the technical language of surveyors, so I'll restate what I understand the question to be.

A surveyor is `Elevation` units above the surface of a spherical planet. He observes a point `B` that is `Angle` degrees above the horizon, `Distance` units away. The angle can be below the horizon too, in which case `Angle` is negative. Find `Height`, the distance between point `B` and the surface of the planet.

[image]

(Planet not to scale.)

The problem can be decomposed into a simple geometric form.

[image]

Everything in this diagram is known except for `Height`. We have two sides of the triangle and one angle, so we can apply the [Law Of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

```
let a = Elevation + Radius
let b = Distance
let c = Height + radius
let gamma = Angle + 90 degrees
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab*cos(gamma)
c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 - 2ab*cos(gamma))
Height + Radius = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 - 2ab*cos(gamma))
Height = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 - 2ab*cos(gamma)) - Radius
```

If you're doing survey work on a tiny tiny sphere, then the horizon is lower than it would be on Earth. Replace `90` in the above equations with the angle between the horizon and the direction of gravity.

Comment: I assume it's not homework, since the OP didn't specify. As for me, I am not a student; I just like geometry and drawing stick figures in MS Paint.

Comment: Comment was intended for OP - my mistake ;)